# A file containing exports

Tags: python, filenames

I have a file containing the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser/squish-5.0-xyz/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/myuser/squish-5.0-xyz/lib
```

I don't what to place it in my ~/.bashrc. What extension would you give such a file? install_squish-5.0.sh or paths_squish-5.0.ini, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Extension doesn't really matter, but I'd name it `.sh` since this is shell commands, not a set of `option: value`.

But be careful that if you don't include those lines in your `.bashrc`, you will need to `source` it anytime you need these variables in a new terminal.

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$ source /pat/to/my_conf.sh
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/myuser/squish-5.0-xyz/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the extension should be `.sh`, but that's a bit cumbersome in this case. Just put the script, for instance, `$HOME/bin` and `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` in `$HOME/.bashrc`. Now you can `. mypyenv` from anywhere. (The `.` is the historical version of the `source` command.)

For a more general solution to this problem, see the `modules` package. http://modules.sourceforge.net/